# Atoms In Space - More Specifically Helium

Tags: atoms, space

I've read several articles regarding the limited supply of helium gas on our planet and one that many scientists/engineers require for their research. I suppose if the government were to issue any mandates limiting the commercial sale of helium it would be bursting balloons leaving behind pouty children in its wake. Now, I know the proceeding observation is probably oversimplified but the article didn't mention the 'life of helium' after earth.

As far as I understand it, untethered helium will float into space leaving us in want once it is all gone. So then, imagining a helium atom floating beyond our atmosphere, where will it ultimately arrive? Does the earths magnetic field prevent the helium atom from escaping too far from our planet? Or, do the solar winds sweep those loose atoms into deeper space?

I know the space vacuum is not perfect and full of different elements and I would imagine the distance between these atoms is great. Will the helium atom eventually bond with other atoms -- given a strong enough electromagnetic attraction -- and form new elements??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Helium Disappear from Earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78586/)

Comment: Let supply and demand take care of it.  Once HE becomes scarce enough the price will go up and price out party balloons.  We are not going to just one day run out of helium for research.   The free marketplace works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in this specific area, but there goes my answer:

Helium has neutral net charge and a spherically symmetrical electron distribution. It is in the "noble gases" family in the periodic table, therefore it interact very weakly with other atoms, and it does not bond easily.

Due to its charge neutrality, I would guess that Helium suffers almost no influence from Earths magnetic field (at least not enough to hold it in a circular trajectory), so it is free to be ejected to outer space. Solar radiation is enough to push particles that have a size in the order of $10^{-5}\textrm{m}$, so Helium atoms are light/small enough to be pushed away by radiation pressure. Since it wont bound with other atoms, it will probably just roam in outer space. The stability of Helium-4 atoms is the larger among all noble gases, and consequently among all atoms.

Most Helium will go into space, but I think some of it is trapped inside minerals from the time Earth formed. As stated in the link provided by @kyle kanos, helium is really diluted in Earth's atmosphere, with about 5.2 parts per million. So even if it does not scape our atmosphere it still would be really scarce just from dilution.

Comment: is correct. I would just add that earth's helium is constantly being replenished by the alpha decay of various radioactive elements, most notably uranium and thorium.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This is exactly what I wanted to know. I checked the link Kyle provided, but it was a little vague with details similar to what I found in the news article. I will be sure to accept your post once I increase my reputation!

Answer (score 0):

As stated, helium is inert, so it will not form compounds with other elements.  In addition, once it is freely released into the atmosphere, it will quickly rise to very high altitudes, and I assume that it would be stripped away by the solar wind.  Despite this, I don't anticipate running out of helium in the near future.  Helium is a small constituent of natural gas, and was formed underground via alpha decay.  The radioactive processes which are undergoing alpha decay should continue for some time, and natural gas producers should also keep extracting helium from natural gas, because it is a valuable byproduct, and because it doesn't burn.  Thus, while the supply of helium is limited by the rate of alpha decay in natural gas deposits, that limited supply should continue for some time to come.

Comment: The fiasco that is the privatization of the BLM Helium program suggests otherwise - to the natural gas folks, separating out the He is a pain in the neck and not worth their time.