# Where do atoms of H and He go when they rise in the atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, earth, atmospheric-science, hydrogen

What happens to atoms/molecules of H and He when we let them freely fly in atmosphere do they get into space? Is there any particular way to enumerate the 'force' that drives them upwards? Does anybody know how this force changes with their altitude/distance from Earth's surface?

Comment: They float to the top of the atmosphere, eventually, but unless they get extra energy from somewhere, such as a cosmic ray or solar radiation, they stay there. They can't go higher, any more than you can hover over a swimming pool, once you reach the surface after a dive .There are duplicates on this site related to this question, e.g. helium filled weather balloons, etc.

Comment: @AcidJazz: "unless they get extra energy from somewhere" — they can also get energy from other particles in the atmosphere, and get up to escape velocity via random collisions.  See [Jeans escape.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_escape)  However, this is (apparently) not the dominant process by which H & He escape Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Helium Disappear from Earth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78586/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks Michael, I missed Maxwell distribution completely, if I do an answer I will include it.

Answer (score 2):

For any sample of atoms in a gas they have a range of speeds.  The likelihood of any atom having any particular speed is given by a probability distribution called the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.  But the main point is that low mass atoms are more likely to have high speeds.  For hydrogen and helium at temperatures typical of Earth's atmosphere there is a small but significant fraction which have speeds that are greater than the escape speed (the speed needed to escape Earth's gravity entirely and go zipping off "to infinity").  Of course, on the way up through the atmosphere they tend to collide with other atoms, but even if we just look at the ones high in the atmosphere (where they are unlikely to collide with anything on the way out) there will be a fraction of them with speeds that are greater than the escape speed.  These will tend to be "lost to space".

What I've just qualitatively described is the "Jean's escape" mentioned by @MichaelSeifert above.

Comment: I would upvote your answer,  no problem,  if you could answer the other parts of the OP...  _Is there any particular way to enumerate the 'force' that drives them upwards? Does anybody know how this force changes with their altitude/distance from Earth's surface?_

Comment: It is probably best not to think of a force that drives them up.  At any moment a molecule/atom can be thought of as having a "random" velocity that results from the complicated history of its previous collisions.  This vertical component of this velocity is as likely to be up as it is to be down.  So half of the molecules with a sufficiently high speed to escape the Earth "just happen" to be going upwards.

Comment: I was thinking more of density differences that I thought the OP had perhaps overlooked or treated as a buoyant force, which I suppose, in effect they are. As to how they change with altitude, I guess they don't  really, in general they, imo,  keep going up.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that if we were to heat these H/He atoms/molecules would the likelihood of their escape be higher? Would these particles also go higher with increasing temperature??

Comment: @user2820052:  Yes, if the atmosphere is hotter then the molecules will have more energy and will be more likely to escape.

Answer (score -3):

They don't go up and leave earth or its atmosphere. The atoms go up because they are lighter then the other atoms and molecules in the air, but they still have mass. They float over the heavier atoms and molecules. They don't leave earth's orbit or go in space but they go very very high. its all because of the gravity and pressure. Atoms swap places, the lighter ones go up and the heavier ones go down.

Comment: No, this is not correct.  See my answer below.